# How to use Flask development server successfully with Ajax post request?

Tags: python, ajax, flask

I'm currently using Flasks's development server instead of using a separate one because I don't need the extra bulk. My server will not be processing many requests at once, so I feel the development server is fine enough.

**What I'm Trying To Do**

I have a python script that I'm trying to run with the click of a button on a web page. This web page is run on an Apache 2 web server on Ubuntu.

**What I've Done**

I've installed Flask and tried to post to my python script, but I always get this error:

```
* Serving Flask app "ResetPOE" (lazy loading) 

* Environment: production WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment. Use a production WSGI server instead. * Debug mode: on
```

It always returns to my error block in my Ajax request and never to my success block. I do not get any return JSON from my Python script. I just want to know whether or not my script ran, I don't necessarily need any output from the script itself.

P.S. my Python may be incorrect, but I haven't even gotten it to recognize it yet, so that's been on the back burner for now. I'm just trying to get the post request to be successful.

ajax.js

```
function ajaxCall(input) {
    var data = {"param" : input}; 
    $.ajax({
        url: "/cgi-bin/reset.py/request",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            console.log("success");
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log("error");
            var err = xhr.responseText;
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
}
```

reset.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
print("Content-type: text/html")
print ("")

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import json
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def sendOK(environ, start_response):
  status = '200 OK'
  output = "Hello World!"
  response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
  start_response(status, response_headers)
  return [output]

@app.route('/request', methods=['POST'])
def processRequest():
  data = request.form["param"]
  # other code to do stuff with the data...
  return Response(json.dumps({"status":"success"}), mimetype="application/json")

if __name__=="__main__":
  app.run(debug=True, threaded=True, host="192.168.1.101")
```

It returns a 200 (OK) in my browser, but I'm not getting any return values, and I can tell my error block is executing and not my success block.

Comment: "but it was telling me that I wasn't able to do this in production mode without using WSGI". I have never seen that with Flask; I think that might be your interpretation of what it was communicating, which is just that the development server should not be used in production. AJAX POST requests work fine with the development server; did you verify that the code works before trying to port over to a different server?

Comment: Indeed, the development server uses WSGI, which is an interface and not itself a server. There are plenty of servers using WSGI, you've picked one with the acronym in its name.

Comment: @roganjosh I was getting this error without using mod_wsgi: "WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment. Use a production WSGI server instead."

Comment: Yep, so I was right. That doesn't have anything to do with whether or not the server will accept AJAX requests. My suggestion would be to drop `mod_wsgi` for now and just keep going on the development server. It will not affect how the _code_ works, so make sure that is functional first before worrying about this.

Comment: @roganjosh I agree with you, but I wasn't able to get to the success block of my ajax request with that route. It was always going to the error block.

Comment: Then the issue isn't with `mod_wsgi`. IMO (and it really is just my opinion) scale the question back out of that context and just focus on the AJAX part.

Comment: @roganjosh If I post a new question would you be willing to aid in the discussion? I really appreciate all your feedback! Nobody working on this with me understands web at all, so I'm a lone wolf here.

Comment: If you post a new question, I may not see it (though I spend too much time on SO). Since the question has no answer, I would still recommend [edit]ing the question back to the development server and fixing the focus on making the AJAX request work. The reality is that asking to make something work with mod_wsgi that doesn't work in development is too much of a stretch, so the question, as is, may possibly be closed.

Comment: If you do edit it back to the original issue, ping me here and I'd be happy to look at it.

Comment: @roganjosh I edited the question, let me know if it makes sense or not. Thanks again for your input, I very much appreciate it!